# Present UIPopoverController with navigation controller

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitableview, uipopovercontroller, uipopover

I am attempting to present a UIPopoverController similar to the bookmark selector in Safari with the title above and the ability to go back and forward. I found this tutorial: http://mobiforge.com/designing/story/using-popoverview-ipad-app-development and  have followed it, yet my navigation bar is not appearing like it should be. Instead, it is appearing like it is recessed in the popover controller and not actually part of the popover controller. Below is the code I have so far. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Code:

```
- (IBAction)addAPrePlan:(id)sender
{
    if (![self.preplanPopoverController isPopoverVisible]) {

        // Initiate the popover controller
        UITableViewController *pp = [[UITableViewController alloc] init];
        pp.navigationItem.title = @"Add a PrePlan";
        UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:pp];
        UIPopoverController *popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:nav];
        popover.delegate = self;
        self.preplanPopoverController = popover;
    }
    else {

        // Dissmiss the popover
        [self.preplanPopoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    }

    // Present the popover controller
    [self.preplanPopoverController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:self.addAPrePlanButton permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: What you are doing is correct. Under iOS 6 and earlier, the border around the popover covers the top part of the navbar. This is normal.

Comment: Can u share a screen shot of what you are actually getting?

Comment: I am using iOS 6.1 so it should not effect it!

Comment: Image: http://s14.postimg.org/cyiuefukh/IMG_0002.png

Comment: As rmaddy said, what you're seeing is normal for iOS 6 and previous versions (that means 6.1 too).

Comment: Then how do they do the bookmark selector in Safari? Using a popoverBackgroundViewClass?

Comment: @JonErickson What is different about the bookmarks popover in Mobile Safari from the image you posted. The appear the same to me.

Comment: Ok, after looking at your image more closely, I do see a difference, but when I copied and pasted your code, it looks exactly like the Safari bookmarks selector, not like your image (using Xcode 4.6.3).

Comment: @rmaddy The NavBar is attached to the tableview in mine where as in the popover in Safari, the navbar is a part of the popover view itself.

Comment: @rdelmar Hmm that is strange. I am using 4.6.3 as well. Something is interfering with it. Are you presenting from a barButtonItem or rect?

Comment: Copied your code exactly. I added a tool bar with one button in IB to the main view controller and assigned the addAPrePlanButton outlet to it.

Comment: your controller is UIViewCOntroller or UITableViewController?

Comment: UITableViewController as it says in the code above...

Comment: So I just created it as well in a separate application and it worked fine. I have no idea what would interfere with it in my original application.